# How environment variables are controlled for different environments with the same build

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have made my first application in React and I am reviewing how to handle the deployment in each environment. My intention was to generate a docker image with this application and when deploying it in Kubernetes the pod would have specific environment variables. And so use the same build for different environments. But I can't get this to work.

I would like to know how you do. Do you generate a build per environment? Do you use environment variables as I comment?

To give a little more information, I have created the application with Vite.js. And the environment variables are the API url, and then the application and tenant id that is used for an authentication with Azure AD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the process.env.NODE_ENV==='production' and base your env variables from that.
Example:

```
const ENV_VAR = process.env.NODE_ENV==='production' ? PROD_VAR : LOCAL_VAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a section in Vite's [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config). It supports [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) files, and I would recommend using the `loadEnv` helper function they provide. In general, it lets you do things like have files like this

```
./.env
./.env.production
./.env.test
./.env.local
```

Each file is a simple key-value pair type file

```
URL=https://my_url.com
```

You can use @sam levine's answer to decide on the environment `process.env.NODE_ENV`. And the last little bit of magic is injecting that variable. Ideally, your CI flow can simple do `export NODE_ENV="production"`, and then it will infer the variables. You can create a bash script in the bin folder that can take care of that setup

```
./bin/build_production.sh
./bin/build_test.sh
```

I have seen it injected into the package.json

```
  "build-production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack build",
```

That has problems on windows

Comment: But in this way you have a build per environment, right? One docker image for production and one for test

Comment: yes, was that the main part of your question. How to not have a build per environment?